# 'getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

I'm trying to create a TCP server in C++. Below is my current code following Beej's tutorial:

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

int main(){
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd;

    // first, load up address structs with getaddrinfo():

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me

    getaddrinfo(NULL, "3490", &hints, &res);

    // make a socket:

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

    // bind it to the port we passed in to getaddrinfo():

    bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
}
```

I'm compiling using g++ (on windows) and getting this error:

> 'getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope

gcc version 6.3.0.

I have looked through the `<ws2tcpip.h>` file and can obviously see `getaddrinfo`'s definition. I have tried adding `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600` above the includes, but that did nothing.

Why won't this code compile?

Comment: Complete side note but boost/asio is much easier to use than the windows API. (Also because boost is C++ and the windows API is "C"). Added benefit it is portable (OS independent)

Comment: Could not reproduce with GCC12.2 provided by MSYS2. I recommend adding the GCC version and distribution to the question.

Comment: gcc version 6.3.0

Comment: Thank you. 6.3's pretty old. If you're not required to use it, consider updating. My collection of installed compilers doesn't include 6.3, unfortunately, (Jumps from 4.9 to 9.3) so I can't offer further insight.

Comment: It compiled fine for me in VSCode with the [documentation recommended MinGW 13.2](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) after I edited my tasks.json to link to `Ws2_32`. I didn't modify the code at all. Although with that said it did seg fault on running stopping in the debugger on this line: `sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);`

Comment: Just for the experiment, comment out `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and see what happens. It'll slow the build a bit, but that should be barely noticeable unless your build machine is rocking a Dorito for a CPU.

Comment: I tried commenting out lean&mean and got the same error. I'm going to install a newer gcc version and if that doesn't work then look into boost/asio

Comment: Suggestion: If you're updating, use MSYS ([installation instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301)). You can use its package manager to install a prebuilt boost and save yourself a few hours of work.

Comment: @drescherjm "*with that said it did seg fault on running stopping in the debugger on this line: `sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);` - the code shown is not checking `getaddrinfo`'s return value for failure before using the `res` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the future who is struggling with this:

1. Update your gcc version using MSYS using these instructions:

   [How can I install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2/30071634#30071634)
2. Use this command:

   `g++ program.cpp -o program -lws2_32`

The code in my question works, just not on my version (6.3) of gcc.